# CRUD operation using form.io and .net mvc

Tags: .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, formio

I am new in https://form.io/. Can any one help me doing CRUD operation using https://form.io/. I have create basic form in https://form.io/#/ and embedded this form in the application through form tag using angularjs-1. I want to perform CRUD operation using this https://form.io/#/ form.

form.io url: https://form.io/#

Comment: Maybe some examples and links to what you have done already or more explanations would help in answering your question.

Comment: you can see in jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/travistidwell/z39b8074/
I have changed form io src url in this. In my form account i have developed basic form which is rendered through above example. I want to do CRUD operation through form io and asp.net mvc

Comment: API documentation here: https://apidocs.form.io/#d43fc691-1008-a1a7-eee8-eb80658922fa

Comment: Building REST servers and clients in ASP.NET https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/apis